# Sqlx join table with same fields

Tags: sql, go

I'm using Go 1.17 with Sqlx but I don't understand how I can join my table correctly.

Here is my structs (my join isn't logic I'm just testing jointure with sqlx)

Table album:

```
package album

import ".../api/v1/movie"

type Album struct {
    ID      string  `json:"id"`
    Title   string  `json:"title"`
    Artist  string  `json:"artist"`
    Price   float64 `json:"price"`
    MovieId int     `json:"movie_id" db:"movie_id"`
    movie.Movie
}
```

Table movie:

```
package movie

type Movie struct {
    ID         string `json:"id"`
    Year       uint16 `json:"year"`
    RentNumber uint32 `json:"rent_number" db:"rent_number"`
    Title      string `json:"title"`
    Author     string `json:"author"`
    Editor     string `json:"editor"`
    Index      string `json:"index"`
    Bib        string `json:"bib"`
    Ref        string `json:"ref"`
    Cat1       string `json:"cat_1" db:"cat_1"`
    Cat2       string `json:"cat_2" db:"cat_2"`
}
```

And this is how I do my join:

```
albums := []Album{}
r.db.Select(&albums, "SELECT * FROM album a INNER JOIN movie m ON (m.id=a.movie_id)")
```

The problem is that these 2 tables have the same `id` field so the album `id` is overridden by the movie id and I lost it.

How can I do to ignore the movie `id` field (because I got it in the `movie_id` field and keep the field `id` for the album `id` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give one of your id fields an `id` tag like:

```golang
type Album struct {
    ID      string  `json:"id" id:"album_id"`
    Title   string  `json:"title"`
    Artist  string  `json:"artist"`
    Price   float64 `json:"price"`
    movie.Movie
}
```

and then make a query which aliases the `id` field to `album_id` like:

```sql
SELECT movie.id as id, album.id as album_id, ... FROM album ...
```

Just keep in mind that you now need to use this column name in your named queries as well.

Comment: Ok so when I'm using a join I can't use `select *` anymore ?

Comment: You might, but then you can't use `id`, since if we do `select album.id as album_id, *` will give you 3 id columns: "album_id", "album.id" and "movie.id". But when you give both id columns a unique name you can do `select album.id as album_id, movie.id as movie_id, *` which will give you 4 id columns: "album_id", "movie_id", "album.id", and "movie.id". In the last case we can discard the un-aliased id columns we got from * since we will not have any field in our structs with the name id.

Comment: I don't know if it's a good idea but maybe I can create another struct just for the join ?

Comment: That should also work. I don't know about the size of your application and if it is worth the investment, but if you are going to be doing a lot of stuff like this where you want to work on relations between structs, you might want to check out [GORM](https://gorm.io/index.html)

Comment: But GORM is not very good for performance as I seen. People recommand to use https://github.com/volatiletech/sqlboiler/

Comment: I have not used sqlboiler so I can't compare the two. In the end every library adds overhead, that is because ORM's in particular do a lot of work in the background. It is a trade off between coding complexity and performance. If you are making an application were every millisecond counts, you might want to stick to doing everything yourself. But most of the time a user won't notice the difference between a 10 and 20 ms response. My main advice was to think about using an ORM, which doesn't really matter, pick one which fits best in your usecase.

Comment: Thank for your answer. The tag id doesn't work for me, it was db tags like this :  `db:"album_id"`